# Can we keep only X number of files rotated by Y MB with Apache rotatelogs

Tags: windows, apache-2.4

**Can we rotate Apache logs keeping n number of backups rotated by size.**

We can rotate apache logs with size by doing following:

ErrorLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe  logs/error_log-%Y-%m-%d.log 20M"

How I can keep only 5 backups always? What I mean is files should be always when it reaches to 20 MB and it should always keep 5 backups.

I am using **Apache 2.4.20** on **windows**.

Answer (score 0):

> [rotatelogs - Piped logging program to rotate Apache logs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/rotatelogs.html)
>
> Synopsis
>
> `rotatelogs [ -l ] [ -L linkname ] [ -p program ] [ -f ] [ -D ] [ -t ]
>   [ -v ] [ -e ] [ -c ] [
>   -n number-of-files ] logfile rotationtime|filesize(B|K|M|G) [ offset ]`
>
> Options
>
> - `-n number-of-files`
>
>   Use a circular list of filenames without timestamps. With `-n 3`, the
>     series of log files opened would be `logfile`, `logfile.1`,
>     `logfile.2`, then overwriting `logfile`. Available in 2.4.5 and later.

With `-n` you'd remove the date from the logfile name:

```
ErrorLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe -n 5 logs/error_log.log 20M"
```